# "Back it up" meaning

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

What does *back it up* mean in this context?

> He can be cocky, but he's got stuff to back it up.

Comment: *back up*: (in) support (of). He can justify his actions, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that his pride or cockiness is not without merit, he has good reason to be cocky.

Comment: I thought the same, it does make sense. Thank you for your explanation.